# Is it Possible to Parse XML Attributes Containing Periods

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am trying to parse XML where some of my attribute names contain periods.

```
<SomeElement someattr.x="45"/>
```

Trying to access this using '**element.@someattr.x**' syntax is giving me trouble due to the extra period. Is there a way to access an attribute containing a period in Actionscript 3, or do I need to pick a different naming convention for my XML attribute?

Comment: From a general practices standpoint, I would go with a different convention.  IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do this.

```
xml.someElement.attribute("someattr.x")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is handled the same as having dashes in element names.

The attribute is referenced using brackets and quotes:

```
@["someattr.x"]
```

Example:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class X extends Sprite
    {
        protected var xml:XML = <root>
                                    <Some-Element 
                                        someattr.x="1" 
                                        someattr.y="2"
                                        someattr.z="3" />
                                </root>;

        public function X()
        {
            trace(xml["Some-Element"].@["someattr.x"]);
            trace(xml["Some-Element"].@["someattr.y"]);
            trace(xml["Some-Element"].@["someattr.z"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> 1
>   2
>   3

Comment: This does not actually work. Gives an unsupported expression error.